# How to conditionally join two tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have two tables which I need to join depending upon their values.

```
TABLE coursemat
+-----+--------+----------+
| txt | price  | material |
+-----+--------+----------+

Table coprices
+--------+----------+
| price  | material |
+--------+----------+
```

They are connected by the `material` key.

If I search `coursemat.material` and find that `coprices.material` is equal, then I must use `coprices.price` instead of the `coursemat.price`.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT coursemat.txt, coursemat.price, coursemat.material, coprices, country
FROM coursemat
JOIN corprices ON coursemat.material = coprices.material;
```

But this isn't quite getting what I want.

Essentially, I want to use `coursemat.price` if `coprices.price` does not exist for the same material and `coprices.material` does exist, then I want to use `coprices.price` instead of `coursemat.price`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly you can use a left join and the IFNULL statement:

```
SELECT
    coursemat.txt, 
    IFNULL(coprices.price, coursemat.price),
    coursemat.material, 
    coprices.country
FROM
    coursemat
LEFT JOIN
    corprices 
    ON coursemat.material = coprices.material;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is COALESCE:

```
SELECT cm.txt, cm.material, COALESCE(cp.price, cm.price) AS price
FROM coursemat cm
LEFT JOIN corprices cp ON cm.material = cp.material;
```

Finally, you could also use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT cm.txt, cm.material, 
CASE WHEN cp.price IS NOT NULL THEN cp.price ELSE cm.price END AS price
FROM coursemat cm
LEFT JOIN corprices cp ON cm.material = cp.material;
```